# URL Object is not recognized

Tags: java

I am writing a web service similar to below. But Java is not recognizing the URL, URLConnection. I am unable to solve this issue.

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
int dataLen = yc.getContentLength() ;
```

Comment: did u write this code in javascript ?

Comment: JavaScript has about as much in common with Java as Carpets do with Cars. The code you've provided looks very much like Java and almost nothing like JavaScript. If you aren't talking about JavaScript, please rephrase your question. If you are, then please provide the JavaScript code that is giving you problems. If that is the JavaScript code, then I suggest you find a beginner level introduction to the language.

Comment: Correction - it is JavaScript not java script.

Comment: @ ninja above.. :) you know you love JavaScript when you get annoyed if some one writes it as "java script"

Comment: Show us the *exact* text of the error you get - the compiler error, the exception, whatever. We can't tell what the problem is without that (although @McDowell has made a good guess!).

Answer (score 1):

This code is Java, not JavaScript. I am guessing that you have not imported the classes from the [java.net](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) package.

- [Tutorial on packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)